# How do I subtract cells from another cell but only if another cell matches a certain text criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am needing help with a call off order spreadsheet that I a working on.
I have two tables on this spreadsheet, 'Call off Sheet' & 'Active Call Offs'.

Photos for reference:

[image: Call off Sheet]

[image: Active Call Offs]

The idea behind it was to create a formula that would find all the entries of a certain cable in the 'Cable Part number' column on the 'Call off Sheet' table and deduct their qtys from that cables total qty in the 'Qty' column in the 'Active Call Offs' table, therefore giving me the total amount of cables remaining.

I did think the below formula would work but it keeps spilling so I must be missing something.

```
=IF(CallOfSheet[Cable Part number]="Cable 34",[@Qty]-CallOfSheet[[Call off qty]],"")
```

Please help, thank you :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your sample is Cable 32, but your formula is Cable 34?

Answer (score -1):

This Solves the issue:

**:Caveat:** *Solution is based of information passed by the OP.*

Formula in cell J16:

```
=H16-SUMPRODUCT((CallOffSheet!$A$16:$A$17=G16)*(CallOffSheet!$B$16:$B$17))
```

[image]

**N.B.**

- Adjust cell references as needed.